# Map Django Model to External API

Tags: python, django, api, dictionary, model

**The context**

I have an external API providing data and allowing to post new data or patch existing one.

*Example of API response :*

```
response = requests.get('http://api/band/4/')
print(response.json()) # {id: 4, name: 'The Beatles'}
```

When I manipulate these objects the API provides I want them to be like instances of a Django model : I want to use them like objects and to be able to create relations to these models the API provides.
I could smartly duplicate data in my database by creating standard models and populating when needed but I don't realy want to.

*Example of manipulation:*

```
class Band(Model): # should not create a new table in database but use API requests instead
    id = PrimaryKey()
    name = StringField()

class User(Mode):
    favourite_band = ForeignKey(Band) # I want to be able to give an instance or directly the pk of a Band
```

**The issue**

Do you have any idea of how I could do that ? Maybe writing my own database Engine for these specific models whose instances are provided by the api ? or just a custom ModelField ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this..

```
response = requests.get(........)
response_data = response.json()
item = Band(**response_data)
#do something with instance.
```

Now, the item is an instance of Band. You could do the operations over the instance. It only writes to the database, only if item.save() command is executed.

Comment: But I don't want to store anything in my database. I want the external API to act like the databse and do http queries instead of SQL queries.

Moreover I don't want to use requets.get manualy anymore in my controllers. I want some kind of adapter/manager to understand that when I call "save" on this model then it does http post on specific url and when I call "model.objects.get" it does a http get.

Comment: Using the Band(**response_data) doesn't save anything in the database until you call item.save(). I imagine the way you would reach your desired goal is to overwrite the methods of the ModelManager to replace the get_queryset() and other methods with your api calls. Also the save/update methods of the model itself.

Comment: Off course it doesn't save if I don't call save, but I need to do something special with the save : a post request. Like you suggested in the second par I think the solution is in ModelManagers. https://github.com/mbylstra/django-wham/blob/master/wham/models.py seems to be a standard implementation for CRUD APIs that do what I need.