# Create model admin page without create table python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms

I'm new to Django and Python and am starting to develop a CMS with this technology with Django CMS.

I need to create a model admin page to manage my lots entity, but i will not have this entity in my database. Basically i will display all entities of lots in the index list, consuming another service like a request. And this is the idea for the other CRUD's.

When `create`, `update`, `delete` I will consume a service to make this operations with the respective entity. For this I will override the CRUD methods of `admin.ModelAdmin`.
Is there a way to do that?

I looked everywhere but without answers.

This is what I already have.

In my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.extensions import PageExtensionAdmin
from .models import LoteDestaque
from .models import LoteDestaqueTest

# from myproject.admin_site import custom_admin_site

@admin.register(LoteDestaqueTest)
```

Here is my `models.py`

```
from .servicos.lotes import * 
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime
from cms.models import CMSPlugin
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField


class LoteDestaqueTest():
    lotes = lotes.buscaLotes()
    lote_id = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(lotes))
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name = _('Nome'))
    imagem = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = _('Imagem'), blank=True, null=True)
    observacoes = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name = _('Observações'), blank=True, null=True)
    descricao = HTMLField(verbose_name = _('Descrição'), blank=True, null=True)
    valor =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name = _('Valor'), blank=True, null=True)
    origem = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = _('Origem'), blank=True, null=True)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = _('Tipo'), blank=True, null=True)
    data_exposicao = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = _('Data Exposição'), blank=True, null=True)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name = _('Ativo'), blank=True)
    criado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    atualizado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Lote em Destaque Test')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Lotes em Destaque Test')
```

My `apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class LoteLeiloesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'leiloes_lotes_plugin'
```

And here is the integration in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'leiloes_lotes_plugin.apps.LoteLeiloesConfig',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_link',
    'cmsplugin_filer_file',
    'cmsplugin_filer_folder',
    'cmsplugin_filer_image',
    'cmsplugin_filer_utils',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_video',
    'projeto'
)
```

Any help is usefull.

Comment: If the data isn't in your database where does it come from? If it's not in your database you don't need to define a model. A model is supposed to tell django how to create the structure of your database. If this data comes from somewhere outside the system you'll need to write an application, not use `ModelAdmin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to reach is to have a ModelAdmin like class so you can get the advantages of django-admin while you handle remote resources (via API), you can try: https://github.com/mbylstra/django-wham the project last commit was in 2015, I hope this can help you in how to tackle this challenge.

Check out this question: [Map Django Model to External API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942686/map-django-model-to-external-api)

Comment: I believe that's what I was looking for. I'll test and I'll answer later. Thank you for your help.